# Windows 7 Parental Controls - How to Disable?

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls

On Windows 7, I'm getting an error saying that "Parental Controls **can** be bypassed because there is an administrator account without a password."  The issue is that there are no other accounts.  I had tried working with a test account called Child to experiment with parental controls.

How do I now just completely disable parental controls so that I don't get this warning message at startup?

The odd thing is that the error message states that "As long as an administrator account has no password, any user can bypass or turn off parentals controls."  Which is exactly what I want to do.  I just don't know how to navigate to the right control panel to turn off parental controls.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does your primary account have a password? If not, create one. Then in the control panel turn off parental controls.

Comment: I'd rather not have a password on my primary account.  While there could be argument that this is not wise, must I have one in order to turn off parental controls?

Comment: Potentially yes.

Comment: @Adam you can always remove your password later.

Answer (score 0):

go start Control Panel click on user accounts and family safety click parental controls put in the admin password and then choose your user and turn it off or change your account to an admin acount. hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

its as simple as this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cLPnU2JFms
open user accounts click on your account then goto user account control near the bottom
you will see a bar adjust it to the level you want it this controls how you are notified including parental control thought one of you wise cracks woul;d have known this messin about with passwords and all that rubbish lmao gl

**This will downgrade the protection level of the whole system. Not advisable for what you want!**

Answer (score -1):

go to control panel to programs and features and choose windows live essentials- then click uninstall/change  then it will prompt you with a screen to asnwer that same question- that you want to uninstall or change one or more of windows live essentials.
the next screen presents you with some checkboxes, family safety is probably the bottom one.  click it and continue removing.