# Change parental controls on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls

I installed parental controls on Windows 7 under Administrator,instead of user, now everything is blocked and I'm unable to go 3 seconds without confirming a password again. I go to Control Panel, then User Accounts and Family Safety, then Parental Controls. I click and see Computer Administrator (Password Protected) and two other users, but cannot find anywhere at Admin to enter a password to undo this. I have the password, just can't find a spot to enter. PLEASE, this is agony.

Comment: Can you get in using standard user account-using admin password when asked or you can setup a new admin account[without controls] you should be able to get into the controls to do the changes you need.

Comment: See this  http://superuser.com/questions/20714/windows-7-parental-controls-how-to-disable

Comment: And this...http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7security/thread/25fd2b1a-58e3-4648-b6a7-90fff12027c2

Answer (score 1):

[How to Setup (and disable) and Use Parental Controls in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/95139-parental-controls-setup-use.html). I know it says Vista, but it should nearly the same steps. You might, also, be able to turn it off from the *Services* Management Console.

Stopping the Parental Controls service:
- Click **Start**
- Type in *Services*
- Select the option label just **Services**
- Scroll down the list to **Parental Controls**
- [Right Click] **Parental Controls**
- Select **Stop**

*Might be prompt by UAC. Enter your password when prompted*